# DOM xpath html extraction

Tags: dom, xpath

I am importing some html into a dom document ans use xpath to extract the html part I am interested in. See below:

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML('$myHtmlFileHere');
$xpath_dom_doc = new DomXPath($dom);
$dom_object = $dom_document->query('myPathHere');

Here below the html structure "returned":

```
<div>GROUP A</div>
<span>aaa</span>
<span>zzz awesome</span>
<span>eee</span>

<div>GROUP B</div>
<span>fff</span>

<div>GROUP C</div>
<span>zzz</span>
<span>uuu</span>
<span>iii</span>
<span>rrr</span>
```

As you see I have categories (GROUP A, GROUP B and GROUP C). In the spans below each category I have information related to the category. What I would like is send to a db the span content with the related category. The problem that I am confronted to is that the div tag of the category is not wrapping the spans. So I do not see how I can manage that. hope someone can help. thank you in advance. Cheers. Marc

Comment: Hello Mahmoud. I unfortunately did not found a way to explain the situation in a shot form...

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud for the title correction... I am not sure though that is deserves a downvote (Relax)...

Comment: Mahmoud, there seems to be "NO BETTER WAY" to stop someone solving his problem using StackOverflow than downvoting his post.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the `following-sibling` xpath function? You should be careful, though, and only select the siblings up to a next `div`.

For example, tested with [xsh2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
$div = //div[2] ;
ls $div/following-sibling::span[count(preceding-sibling::div)=1+count($div/preceding-sibling::div)] ;
```

Comment: Hello choroba. Thanks for taking time to try helping out. Actually looking towards the solution you propose helped me find the solution. Thank you very much. Cheers :)

Comment: @Marc: If your solution is different from mine, it might be interesting if you shared it here for other people's benefit.